# Spring Security 403 http status

Tags: rest, http, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am implementing Spring Security on a Spring Boot 2.0.1 project.

I have some web services that used to work fine before Spring Security implementation. But now, they don't.

This is the error message displayed in REST client.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-27T11:14:40.080+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/lsm/notification/getCurrentUserNotifications"
}
```

and the same error on google chrome :

[image: 403 Error]

Below is the controller listing the services:

```
package com.sap.lsm.web;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.sap.lsm.dao.NotifiedUserRepository;
import com.sap.lsm.dao.UserNotificationRepository;
import com.sap.lsm.entities.NotifiedUser;
import com.sap.lsm.entities.UserNotification;
import com.sap.lsm.service.UserNotificationService;

@RestController
public class UserNotificationController {

@Autowired
private UserNotificationService userNotificationService;

@Autowired
private UserNotificationRepository userNotificationRepository;

@RequestMapping(value="/notification/getCurrentUserNotifications", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<UserNotification> getCurrentUserNotifs() {
    return userNotificationService.getCurrentUserAllNotifications();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/notification/getCurrentUserNotSeenNotifications", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<UserNotification> getCurrentUserNotSeenNotifs() {
    return userNotificationService.getCurrentUserNotSeenNotifications();
}

@RequestMapping(value="/notification/deleteNotification/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteNotification(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    userNotificationService.deleteNotification(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/notification/getNotification/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public UserNotification getNotification(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    UserNotification notification = this.userNotificationService.getNotification(id);

    if(!notification.equals(null)) {
        notification.setStatus("seen");
        userNotificationRepository.save(notification);
    }

    return notification;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/notification/markCurrentUserNotificationsAsSeen", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void markCurrentUserNotificationsAsSeen() {
    userNotificationService.markAllNotificationsAsSeen();
}
}
```

And this is the Spring Security Config :

```
package com.sap.lsm.config;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private RequestFilter requestFilter;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public SpringSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
}

public void setbCryptPasswordEncoder(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.cors()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/lsm/listCustomers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/addCustomer").hasAnyAuthority("CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getAllCustomers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getOldCustomers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getCustomers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getCustomer/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/deleteCustomer/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/cancelCustomer/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/restoreCustomer/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/updateCustomer/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getLSMUsers").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/addLSMUser").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/getLSMUser/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/deleteLSMUser/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/cancelLSMUser/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/restoreLSMUser/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/updateLSMUser/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/notification/getCurrentUserNotifications/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/notification/getCurrentUserNotSeenNotifications/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/notification/deleteNotification/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/notification/getNotification/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/lsm/notification/markCurrentUserNotificationsAsSeen/*").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN","CONSULTANT")
            .antMatchers("/assets/**","/login","/*").permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilterBefore((Filter) new JWTAuthorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(requestFilter, ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

}
```

If you need JWT authentication and authorization filters, i'll post them later on .

Please help me,
Thanks

** update **

The role of the connected user is ADMIN.

The path /lsm is declared as property in the pom.xml as follows:

```
<m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/lsm</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
```

This root path is used to run the application under Jenkins (integration server)

Comment: Can you please also specify the role that the user has with which you have currently logged in?

Comment: Is `/lsm` the `servlet.context-path` or the `servlet.servlet.path` in your application. Or is it simply being deployed? I suspect either option 1 or 3 in that case remove `/lsm` from your security mappings.

Comment: No... As you noticed all urls are restricted to authenticated users. If the urls don't match, that is the catch all. If case 1 or 3 is happening the URLs won't match (as they match from the root of the application not the root of the server!).

Comment: Do you add the prefix `ROLE_` to the JWT roles you are checking against? Or do you just add `ADMIN`?

Comment: I just add ADMIN as role